# The difference between 'схожу' and 'спускаюсь'

Tags: значения

What's the difference between

> Я схожу вниз по лестнице/ по трапу.

and

> Я спускаюсь вниз по лестнице/ по трапу.

Are there any subtle differences in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much in meaning as in register with **схожу** being vernacular and thus of lower register.

Semantically they in principle could differ because **схожу** means **walk down** while **спускаюсь** means **descend** which can be performed by means other than walking.

But practically in everyday use more often than not **спускаюсь** implies descend by means of walking, because this is the most common way of descending physically. And certainly when it's a descent down the stairs.

There's difference in my view between shades of meaning of these words in different tenses in the context of descending down the stairs. The perfective aspect of **сходить** in the past and future tenses (**сошёл, сойду**) tends to emphasize the manner of descending, that is by walking, therefore if there's no need to stress this detail **спустился** and **спущусь** would sound more appropriate as they're neutral in this respect.

Comment: what’s vernacular and low about e. g. “Моряк сошёл на берег?”

Comment: "Моряк сошёл с ума" ;)

Comment: the OP gave a specific context, where the verb **сходить** is a synonym of **спускаться**, in that specific context it is of a lower register, there're other specific cases where it's register isn't low, like those mentioned in the comments, but in these cases **сходить** is NOT a synonym of **спускаться** and cannot be replaced with it

Comment: ну да, если трап самодвижущийся, эскалатор, то спускаться можно и не сходя :-D

Comment: "На дальней станции сойду - трава по пояс". In my perception "сойти" would be not lower register but somewhat poetic/archaic/pretentious one. And passenger "walking down" an airliner or railroad car also uses the stairs/trap to do it

Comment: `(сошёл, сойду) tends to emphasize the manner of descending` - or the very process of it. When casual "спускаюсь" is somewhat hinting how non-important that process was. Kind of, I was there, then I got here, I cursory mention it for mere story continuity, but nothing more into it.

Comment: **Сходить** is not necessarily about descending, and it refers to _the fact of leaving some place_ which must be present in the context (the imaginary _train_ in your example). It is OK _сходить **с корабля** по горизонтально положенному трапу_, not to mention trivial cases with perfective verb forms where type of motion doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Typically a transport is going over the surface, being above it. Try to descent from the subway. Or to descend from a cave, from a basement, a cellar.

Comment: Когда он _сходил_ с эскалатора, шедшего _вверх_, он споткнулся и упал. **No** idea of descending here.